# How to segment a number to multiple unique numbers

Tags: algorithms

I have a problem that I want to speed up by using a GPU. This GPU runs some code that let's parallelize the computation and only has one number, $k$, to determine the uniqueness of the code it is currently running.

The problem this GPU needs to speed up is the checking of all nodes distances between them at all time steps. However, I only want to check the distances between two nodes once. Therefore I only what to check Node 0 with Node 10 but not Node 10 with Node 0. Also, I don't want to check Node 0 with Node 0.

Having explained this, and having $T$ time steps $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, T\}$ and $N$ nodes $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, N\}$, I know that there are $\frac{N(N-1)}{2} \cdot T$ distances to check.

I have to let the GPU loop $k$ through these $\frac{N(N-1)}{2}\cdot T$ different combinations, I know how to get the time step, $T_\text{step} = \lfloor\frac{2k}{N(N-1)} \rfloor$, however, I don't know how to get the two nodes numbers from this $k$ values or the remainder of the $T_\text{step}$ calculation.

Here is an example with $T = 3$ and $N = 5$, of the numbers I want to get from this $k$ value:

| $k$ | Time Step | Node 1 ID | Node 2 ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 0 | 1 | 4 |
| 7 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| 8 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 9 | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| 10 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 11 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 12 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 13 | 1 | 0 | 4 |
| 14 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 15 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 16 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 17 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 18 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 19 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 20 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 21 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 22 | 2 | 0 | 3 |
| 23 | 2 | 0 | 4 |
| 24 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 25 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 26 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 27 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 28 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 29 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the results from below,
\begin{gather}
   T_{step} = \left\lfloor\frac{2k}{N(N-1)} \right\rfloor, \quad n_1 = \left\lfloor \frac{1+\sqrt{1 + 8k_1}}{2} \right\rfloor, \quad n_2 = k_1 - \frac{n_1(n_1-1)}{2} \\ k_1 = k \mod \frac{N(N-1)}{2}
\end{gather}

---

In my past experience with parallelization, the simplest approach is to share copies of a common data structure with all the cores, where the $k^{th}$ entry has all the information required for run $k$. However, this approach does add overhead on RAM and computation.

Now since the iterations are parallelized (and assumedly independent), the order in which the combinations of Time Step, Node 1 ID, and Node 2 ID doesn't matter. Also, for your problem, the ordering between Node 1 ID and Node 2 ID doesn't matter. So to understand the calculations better, I'm reordering the first time step's iterations as follows.

| k | Time Step | Node 1 ID | Node 2 ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 4 | 1 |
| 8 | 0 | 4 | 2 |
| 9 | 0 | 4 | 3 |

If we look at the subset for the first occurrence of each Node 1 ID value $n_1$, we see the relationship $k = \frac{n_1(n_1-1)}{2}$.
| k  | Time Step | Node 1 ID | Node 2 ID |
| -- | --------- | --------- | --------- |
| 0  | 0         | 1         | 0         |
| 1  | 0         | 2         | 0         |
| 3  | 0         | 3         | 0         |
| 6  | 0         | 4         | 0         |

Solving for $n_1$, we can get the value of Node 1 ID at the given $k$. Fortunately, we can get an analytical formula in this case using the quadratic formula (the negative case is clearly not the one we want)
$$n_1^2 -n_1 - 2k = 0 \rightarrow n_1 = \frac{1+\sqrt{1 + 8k}}{2}$$

Now the above formula will give a proper integer for $n_1$ at the iterations where $n_1$ changes. All other iterations, it will give a fractional value. So similar to what you did with the time step formula, we floor it
$$n_1 = \left\lfloor \frac{1+\sqrt{1 + 8k}}{2} \right\rfloor$$

But the above only works for the first time step. The node pattern repeats every time step; so we just have to cut off the prior time steps iterations first.
$$n_1 = \left\lfloor \frac{1+\sqrt{1 + 8k_1}}{2} \right\rfloor, \quad k_1 = k - T_{step} \cdot \frac{N(N-1)}{2} = k \mod \frac{N(N-1)}{2}$$

For Node 2 ID $n_2$, we first cut off the prior repeat iterations under Time Step and Node 1 ID, then assign a value based on the remainder. Fortunately this calculation is simpler (usually is for the last parameter in such a systematic parameter analysis).
$$n_2 = k_2, \quad k_2 = k_1 - \frac{n_1(n_1-1)}{2}$$

You could also use this methodology to derive the formulae for your current ordering; but it may be more tedious and the formula may be more ugly.